# how to disable or stop Jquery fade out function

Tags: jquery

I have a Jquery fadeout function in my default layout like :

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){$('.alert').fadeIn(2000);}, 5000);
});
```

but I want to disable this function on a particular page.
How to stop this. please help.
I have tried this :

```
$(function() {

  $('.alert').stop().fadeIn(2000);
});
```

but not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You shoud add this code before $('.alert').stop().fadeIn(2000);

```
callbacks.disable( ".alert" );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m3eaomf6/

Comment: Uh, no. What? Your JSFiddle cancels the fade in because it throws a ReferenceError and never gets past there in the script.

Answer (score 0):

On the particular page you can add another class to the element, say `.disabled`, and then have the code in the main layout be like:

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function(){$('.alert:not(.disabled)').fadeIn(2000);}, 5000);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this,

```
 $('.alert').clearQueue().fadeIn(2000);
```

*Remove from the queue all items that have not yet been run.*

Here is reference [link](https://api.jquery.com/clearQueue/)